# ListFiles() only shows folders but no files - AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-file

I need to iterate over a folder, going throughout all the files in it. However, It says that my folder is empty (size = 0). I did some more test and find out that .listFiles() was giving me only folders and not any files (by files I mean .txt, .png, .pdf etc)

In the sample below, ImagesTeste has 6 .jpg images, but none of them are found by .listFiles()

```
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DCIM/ImagesTeste";
            Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
            File directory = new File(path);
            File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);

            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());

                }
```

Comment: You did not tell that this was only using an Android 11 device.

Comment: `String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DCIM/ImagesTeste";
            Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
            File directory = new File(path);
` Better: `File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM/ImagesTeste");
`

Comment: Or `File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "ImagesTeste"); `

Comment: Thanks for your comments :) Well, I didn´t knew that this was only using an Android 11 Device, my divice is indeed a android 11, but how did you know? And how does that impact the .listFiles() or others methods that Im trying to use? Besides, none of the sugested solutions have worked, still geting size 0 and no acess to the images.

Comment: Depending on your Android 11 device the default Camera app will store its files in DCIM/Camera or Pictures directory. Please try. You will see the fotos. It happened to me before thats why i know. And ofcourse... if your app had created files in that directory you could list them too. On an Android 11 device in principle an app only sees its own files. Except for media files in mentioned directories and some other.

Comment: I have moved a folder, named "ImagesTeste" to the DCIM directory, thats why Im using it, cause that's where I've puted my folder. Inside this folder (ImagesTeste) are 6 images. I have also tried to acess DCIM/Camera and it keeps not showing any image files,  even though when I go there in my device there are hundreds of images. More, I have also tested other directories, and it keeps showing only folders, not .pdf files or .word files or anyother kind of files

Comment: `have moved a folder, named "ImagesTeste" to the DCIM directory, ` You did that with your PC i think. But then those files do not belong to your app.

Comment: No, I did that on my device. I ziped the file in my computer, than used we-transfer to get the link and download it on my device, then unziped on the device and moved it to DCIM. The files are in my device, I want to open that folder and acess the images

Comment: The question is then: Who/which app  downloaded those files? Your app? Or who/which app moved them? Your app? If not your app then your app is not the owner of those files and your app will not see them. That's Android 11. New times did come.

Comment: No, none of those were done by my app. My app has only the itention to acess that folder and process the images

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. **What I had to do was explicitly request the permission** `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (It's not enough to include the permission in the manifest file, you also have to request the permission from the user).

With React Native you can request permissions using [PermissionsAndroid](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid).

With Android SDK you can request permissions using [ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#allow-system-manage-request-code)